# Running jQuery Functions Document Ready & Window Resize in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, window-resize

I currently have a working script to resize some divs according to the highest size one on (document).ready in WordPress. I also want to incorporate for whenever the window is resized, it should fire the same functions. I've been having a lot of trouble from trying to add (window).resize - I've tried to combine them, make an outside function, and even just copy & pasting the same functions (but with window resize instead of document ready as the trigger). No dice... any help with how to combine these two triggers in WP would be very appreciated!

The working code I have for Document Ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.service-row').each(function() {
  var highestBox = 0;

$('.service-item', this).each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
    highestBox = $(this).height();
  }
});

$('.service-item', this).height(highestBox);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap that code inside a resize handler and also trigger resize event on page load to cause the initial run

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.service-row').each(function() {
      var highestBox = 0;

      $('.service-item', this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = $(this).height();
        }
      });

      $('.service-item', this).height(highestBox);
    });
  // trigger resize on page load
  }).resize()


});
```

Comment: Sweet!! Thank you so much! This fixed it on iPhone. My only problem now is when I resize the browser window they still get cut off/stay the same initial size unless I refresh, any ideas?

Comment: Can't help without seeing it live

Comment: Gotcha, here is my site: [link](http://flintflux.com/) The boxes under "What We Do" are what's being effected.